# Is it possible to Programatically Set and Remove Widget from the home screen in Android..?

Tags: android, widget

Plz see the problem below,

I have an Android application having Widget functionality, everything is working fine, but After installing my application I manually need to set the widget to the home screen from the widget section. Now I want to do it through my Application (i.e. I'm planning to give One CheckBox, in my application's setting section and when user will Check the CheckBox, Widget should appear to the home screen and when user will UnChecked the  CheckBox, Widget should removed from the screen. Is it Possible...? ). Hope You understand what I'm trying to say...? Thanks..!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**NO**.its not possible..home screen widget adding and removing only done by the user but not programmatic..because widgets are under the home screen you don't have any permission to add it or remove it from home screen..