# Create widget from Activity

Tags: android, widget

I've created an android app und a widget. I can add the widget to my homescreen by long-pressing the homescreen->widgets->....
Is there the possibility to add a widget to my homescreen by code? Because many users don't know widgets and I want to simplyfy the usage. Just adding a button "Start widget" and if pressed, my widget appears on the homescreen.
Best Regards

Comment: check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19462605/is-it-possible-to-programatically-set-and-remove-widget-from-the-home-screen-in/19462656#19462656

Answer (score -1):

I really appreciate the feature  you looking for will give better user interface in your app.

Adding widget technically(`binding appwidget`)is  much sensitive task as there are lots of security violations can be done by using this.  hence this feature has been made much complex almost not possible.

You can google it anywhere the result will not be that much optimum for this question...